# controller.modelAndView is null in integration test

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing

Given this action in a controller:

```
def listBlockedMembers() {
    def blocked = UserBlock.findAllByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser)

    render(view:'listBlockedMembers', model:[blocked:blocked])
}
```

in my integration test the model and view works fine:

```
def blocked = controller.modelAndView.model['blocked']
assertEquals 2, blocked.size()
```

but if I pass the model from the action like this:

```
def listBlockedMembers() {
    def blocked = UserBlock.findAllByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser)
    [blocked:blocked]
}
```

I get a null pointer exception accessing `controller.modelAndView` (null pointer on the modelAndView attribute itself)

My integration test extends `GroovyTestCase`.  While the first action works, the second is less code, and I wonder why the null pointer exception would occur.  In development the gsp renders the same for both actions.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a [Grails bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8462) for this, and it has to do with the two return types being handled differently:

> There are 2 scenarios being discussed here. One is a scenario where a method in a controller returns a Map and one is a scenario where the method in a controller does not return a Map. For the case where the method does not return a Map, for the sake of this discussion we are talking about the method having invoked the render method.

So it looks like when returning a map, it may be better to treat it as a regular method (and dealing with the returned value) than calling `controller.modelAndView`.  For example:

```
Map response = controller.listBlockedMembers()
assert response.blocked
```